# Which profile gets loaded when invoking WSL's 'bash -c' in Powershell?

Tags: bash, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-server

While in an active Powershell session with WSL installed and setup (Debian), running `bash -c 'whoami'` shows the Active Directory user that I'm authenticated to the host machine as. However, running `bash -c 'env'` doesn't show the environment variables that I've got set in my `/home/user` and `/mnt/c/Users/user` profiles. Which profile, if any, is getting used when executing single Bash commands from within Powershell?

---

### Edit:

I've found the default system `.bashrc` at `/etc/bash.bashrc` and added the wanted `export` statements to it, but they are still not showing when running `bash -c 'env'`.

### Edit 2:

Adding the exports to `/etc/profile` didn't have the desired effects either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ echo $-
```

will display a character string identifying properties of the bash session within which you are running the 'echo' command.

In a login shell or interactive subshell launched from a login shell I can see the letter "i" in that character string. In a bash session started just to run a command, e.g. using 'bash -c', the letter "i" is missing from this output, indicating that the session is not interactive. Your .bashrc file (or system-level equivalents) aren't run in bash sessions that are not interactive. Here is an example from a RH7 linux box. I see the same difference on my mac running macos.

```
~ $ ssh c7a
Last login: Tue Dec 31 07:29:29 2019 from gateway
[builder@c7a ~]$ echo $-
himBH
[builder@c7a ~]$ bash -c 'echo $-'
hBc
[builder@c7a ~]$
```

So I believe the answer to your question of which profile is run for single commands using bash -c is "none".

Comment: Ah that's a nice command to know! `bash --help` shows that Shell options can be used during invocation, so using `bash -ic` proved to use `/etc/bash.bashrc`. Now I'm curious as to why `/etc/profile` wasn't used if those commands are being invoked in a non-interactive session...

Comment: /etc/profile is part of the "profile" startup scripts like ~/.bash_profile. The profile scripts only get run when you start a "login shell". That is usually the first shell you open locally or via ssh (when you log in). Shells launched from the login shell can be interactive but they are not considered login shells. So basically you can count on the "rc" startup scripts like ~/.bashrc to run everytime a new interactive shell is launched, but can only count on the "profile" scripts to run when you login. You can always source whatever script you need as part of a "bash -c" command string.